# React - Individual Counter Components - Parent Increase/Decrease All

Tags: reactjs, components, parent-child, counter

WARNING: REACT NEWBIE WHO IS STILL VERY MUCH LEARNING.

I have a challenge that is requiring me to build a simple React Counter app. The rules are: No use of Redux, no use of hooks. Each counter functions independently to increment or decrement with a button click. AND! The Parent component can increment or decrement ALL Counter components.

EX of individual increment/decrement:

Counter 1 = 2

Counter 2 = 4

Counter 3 = 6

EX Increment ALL will make the following changes:

Counter 1 = 3

Counter 2 = 5

Counter 3 = 7

I know this involves a callback function defined within the parent component, I'm just confused as to how  to implement this. I have a very non-efficient way of doing this in place now. Can anyone lead me in the right direction of how to setup this up in a more efficient way?

Here is my **Parent**:

```
import React from 'react';
import Counter from './components/Counter';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.counterElement1 = React.createRef();
    this.counterElement2 = React.createRef();
    this.counterElement3 = React.createRef();
  }

  handleAllIncrease = () => {
    console.log("hello App Increase")
    this.counterElement1.current.handleIncrease();
    this.counterElement2.current.handleIncrease();
    this.counterElement3.current.handleIncrease();
  }

  handleAllDecrease = () => {
    console.log("hello App Decrease")
    this.counterElement1.current.handleDecrease();
    this.counterElement2.current.handleDecrease();
    this.counterElement3.current.handleDecrease();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={() => this.handleAllIncrease()}>Increase all</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleAllDecrease()}>Decrease all</button>
          <Counter  ref={this.counterElement1} />
          <Counter  ref={this.counterElement2}/>
          <Counter  ref={this.counterElement3}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is my **Child**:

```
import React from 'react';


class Counter extends React.Component {


    state = {
        num: 0,
    }

    handleIncrease = () => {
        console.log("hello increase")
        this.setState({
            num: this.state.num + 1,
        })

    }

    handleDecrease = () => {
        console.log("hello decrease")
        this.setState({
            num: this.state.num - 1,
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{this.state.num}</p>
                <button onClick={this.handleIncrease}>+</button>
                <button onClick={this.handleDecrease}>-</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Counter;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you are a newbie so will not try any fancy stuff and try to find a simple solution to this.

let's have a parent component App define as

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counterA: 0,
      counterB: 0,
      counterC: 0
    }
  }

  handleAllIncrement = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      counterA: prevState.counterA + 1,
      counterB: prevState.counterB + 1,
      counterC: prevState.counterC + 1
    }))
  }

  handleAllDecrement = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      counterA: prevState.counterA - 1,
      counterB: prevState.counterB - 1,
      counterC: prevState.counterC - 1
    }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-evenly'}}>
          <Counter counter={this.state.counterA} />
          <Counter counter={this.state.counterB} />
          <Counter counter={this.state.counterC} />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
          <button onClick={this.handleAllIncrement}> + All </button>
          <button onClick={this.handleAllDecrement}> - All </button>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

It contains two methods handleAllIncrement & handleAllDecrement that will increment all the state variable value or otherwise, that's the goal of the parent component. It will also have three variables/state variables that will be passed to the individual counter components.

```
counterA: 0,
counterB: 0,
counterC: 0
```

Now, let's see what the child component does.

```
import React from "react";

class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      num: 0
    };
  }

  handleIncrease = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      num: prevState.num + 1
    }));
  };

  handleDecrease = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      num: prevState.num - 1
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.num + this.props.counter}</p>
        <button onClick={this.handleIncrease}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleDecrease}>-</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

Initially, we define a state variable num as you have that is changed when the increment & decrement is performed individually.

Rest of the stuff is normal to react thing, the only trick I applied is the line

```
<p>{this.state.num + this.props.counter}</p>
```

What this line does it add whatever value passed from the parent to the current state value.

So, for Counter A individually incremented twice so num for A is now 2.
You now clicked increment all button thrice now what will happen is num + props.counter (i.e 3 now) will give 5 and the other will have 3 as the individual state is 0 + passed value is 3.

Here is the running code if you want to play around [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/countershared-khm19?file=/src/Counter.js:409-453)

Comment: OH! Ok I gotcha! Yes, this makes complete sense. Thank you so much for your help AND the thorough explanation!

Comment: Good to know it helped ^.^

Answer (score -1):

Try to use memo.This helps to maintain the cache for every child component.

[react-hook](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html)

Comment: She mentioned no use of hooks.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I would suggest having all the functionality in the parent element. Then define 4 functions in it, handleIncrease, handleDecrease, handleIncreaseAll, handleDecreaseAll. Then I would have an array with the counters to have an index for each counter and the corresponding increasing/decreasing value it has.
In the handleIncrease, as well as for the handleDecrease, you should pass a parameter to determine the index of the current counter and know how much it should increase/decrease. Finally, you should pass those functions to the counters as props, and on the onClick event of each increase/decrease button in Counter you should refer to props.handleIncrease or props.handleDecrease depending the case.